# Proving that the largest number of leaves in an $n$-ary tree of height $k$ is $k^n$

Tags: combinatorics, trees, discrete-mathematics

How to prove that the largest number of leaves in an $n$-tree of height $k$ is $k^n$?

Comment: I won't ask what you've done so far (clearly, it's nothing). But I will give you a hint: *induction*.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I found a solution on the internet :
http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page257.html
 .. last five lines

Comment: @ammarx and do you *understand* the solution? Copying it down and handing it in won't help you.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis I know, but it's a homework question and I have final exams these days so..
but you are right.

Comment: @ammarx It is perfectly fine to answer your question. If you write an answer, you might learn something too along the way!

Answer (score 2):

The claim is that an $n$-ary tree of height $h \geq 0$ has at most $n^h$ leaf nodes. The base step $h=0$ is obviously true. Assume the claim is also true for $h=1,2,\ldots,k$, for some $k \geq 0$. In a tree of height $k+1$, we have a root and $n$ subtrees each of which contain at most $n^k$ leaves. Thus the maximum number of leaves is $n \cdot n^k = n^{k+1}$. This completes the proof.